# python pass os.environ to child gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, python-3.x, environment-variables, subprocess, gnome-terminal

I am creating a new child terminal and passing it the calling shell's environment variables using:

```
currentEnv =os.environ.copy()
print("PARENT: " + currentEnv["PATH"])
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sudo gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'python3 somescript.py'"), env=currentEnv)
```

inside somescript.py I am reporting the $PATH given by the parent:

```
currentEnv = os.environ.copy()
print("CHILD:" + currentEnv["PATH"])
```

My output in the parent terminal is as follows:

```
PARENT: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib:/home/myusername/bin
```

In the child window:

```
CHILD:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

As a result, I recieve lots of "command not found" errors in the child script when it is calling to any executables found in the parent $PATH.

How can I pass the parent's environment variables down to a child process? I thought this was the default behaviour?

Comment: Child processes *do* inherit the parent's environment (including `PATH`). Your issue is that `sudo` specifically limits the environment variables it passes to *its* children (for security).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: you should post it as an answer. The environment is inherited even without specifying `env` parameter. `sudo` is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it appears sudo was the main culprit here - it also highlighted some issues in my ~./bashrc and ~./bash_profile files that led me to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are loosing the environment variables when calling `sudo`

You can keep your environment variables with sudo by using the `-E` switch:

**From the manual:**

```
 -E, --preserve-env

     Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may
     return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

So try:

```
currentEnv =os.environ.copy()
print("PARENT: " + currentEnv["PATH"])
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sudo -E gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'python3 somescript.py'"), env=currentEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, upon realising sudo was the culprit I actually found it to be redundant in my case. Running sudo gnome-terminal (or any other graphical application as root) brings a lot of headaches. I found additional information regarding this [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515198/how-to-run-terminal-as-root)